# django,python keyerror from a kwarg key that isn't there - how do i avoid this?

Tags: python, django

if i have some code:

```
variableA = self.kwarg['maybe']
```

now, 'maybe' is sometimes there and sometimes not. I really don't care if it isn't there - i check if variableA is None down the line - so how do i avoid the oh-so-annoying "keyerror" that pops up when it isn't there?

I just want django to let me set a variable to None!

UPDATE: thanks all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I never used django, but if self.kwarg is a dict, you can use the get() function, which returns None (or an optional default value) for elements not in the dictionary:

```
d = dict()
d.get("abc")              #-> None
d.get("abc", "default")   #-> "default"
```

Answer (score 2):

http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault

> `setdefault(key[, default])`
>   If `key` is in the dictionary, return its value. If not, insert `key` with
>   a value of `default` and return `default`. `default` defaults to `None`.

Applied to your code:

```
variableA = self.kwarg.setdefault('maybe')
# -> variableA is now None
```